# How to count bit sets from a bit string?

Tags: count, mips, bit

I am learning mips and have bought myself a book with with a few tasks.
One of them is to count the number of bits that are set.

I have that given:

bit_string:                     .word 0x00111101

In jave I found a solution but in Mips i have no idde how to solve this problem.

Maybe i can solve this with right shifts?

Comment: Loop through the characters in the string and count all the `1`'s.  If it's already in an `int`, there are [plenty of resources that explain how](https://www.google.com/search?q=count+number+of+bits).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the fast answer.

I don't thinks that ist is in a int.

And yes i saw all of those sites but, i dont kow how they can help

Comment: looks like 'bit_string' in the case is a integer, not a string